# Trouble with router in nextjs 13 when using Layout of antd

Tags: layout, antd, next.js13, next-router

The layout like [this](https://ant.design/components/layout#components-layout-demo-top-side-2)

First is my menu of Sider

```
const menu = [
{
            key: 'product',
            icon: React.createElement(ContainerOutlined),
            label: 'product',
            children: [
                {
                    key: 'product/all',
                    label: 'all',
                },
                {
                    key: 'product/create',
                    label: 'create',
                },
                {
                    key: 'product/setting',
                    label: 'setting',
                },
            ]
        }
]
```

When I click the menu in Sider

```
const clkMenu = (data) => {
        router.replace(data.key);
    }
```

When the first click, it still work like "/product/all"

But in the second click, router.replace still adding a new URL entry into the `history` stack into "/product/all/product/create"

I expected router.replace will work in the right way

Please help me :(